# Preventing queues with JQuery effect() with fixed position elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

**The Situation**

I am using the [`effect()`](https://api.jqueryui.com/effect/) function of JQuery UI. The type of effect doesn't really matter but for the purpose of this question lets use `"bounce"`. This effect is called when a link is clicked, so my complete example code is as follows:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#box').effect('bounce');
});
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8hvvpsww/)

---

**The Problem**

The problem I have, or more the behavior I want to get rid of, is that when you click the link multiple times in quick succession then it queues up the animations. (See the demo, click the link 10 times fast, then release and watch it continue to animate)

---

**The Requirement**

I just want to prevent effects/animations from being queued. In other words, I am looking for clicks to be ignored if the box is already bouncing. Is there anyway I can do this?

---

**The Failed Attempts**

I have already done some research, and I tried a couple of method below but to no success:

```
$('#box').stop().effect('bounce');
```

`stop()` just doesn't seem to have any effect in this case.

```
$('#box').clearQueue().effect('bounce');
```

`clearQueue` actually works in the sense that the effects don't queue, however there are side-effects which causes the layout to mess up. I assume this is because it prevents the effect from returning the styles to their defaults. It may also be related to using a `fixed` position for the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
if( !$('#box').is(':animated') ){ 
    $('#box').effect('bounce');
}
});
```

Comment: That seems to work pretty well actually, hopefully it will be reliable. Not that it's an 'app breaker' if it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, `clearQueue` makes position changes in div but i tried that and it looks like working

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   if ($("#box").is(':animated')) {
       $('#box').effect = null
     }
   else { 
        $('#box').effect('bounce');
   }
});
```

[js fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8hvvpsww/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#box').stop(true).effect({
        effect: 'bounce',
        complete: function() {
            $('#box').removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

`stop(true)` stops and clears the queue immediately but when stopped, `effect()` leaves inline styles after completion. They just need to be removed afterwards.

The benefit of this approach is that the clicks *feel* a little more responsive (for the lack of a better word). The box will seem to react quickly to user's clicks.

However, if you cannot afford to simply remove the `style` attribute upon completion of animation, say you have previously applied inline styles on your object, you can cache them beforehand and re-apply them upon completion, which is demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/8hvvpsww/5/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Although this does work in my example, it would not work if there were already styles applied using the `style` attribute, as they would be removed too. [For example](http://jsfiddle.net/8hvvpsww/4/), red text gets reverted to black.

Comment: true. cache them and re-apply them again. the good thing about my approach (if i can say it so myself) is that it *feels* more responsive in a way that it reacts to user clicks quickly and ignores i.e. stops previous calls. where as the other solutions that i have seen so far, wait for the previously applied animation to complete to allow to animate again. choice is yours of course :)

Comment: A decent defense. I suggest adding that comment to your answer in some way. It's useful info and might be preferred by others. I however will stick with the simpler method that I already accepted as it's much cleaner IMO

Comment: @musefan: just did that. thanks for the prompt suggestion. we are all learning :)